# Lock Not Being Released by Thread at the End of Run Method [Solved]

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

So I'm trying to run a cafe simulation using Java's ReentrantLock and volatile. Basically I have a time thread that supposed to change a volatile variable to false to stop all the other threads from running. But for some reason the Time thread doesn't release the lock and other threads continue to run endlessly.

Here is the code for the main class:

```
package cafesim;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public class CafeSim {

     public static volatile boolean continuetoRun = true;

    static Queue<Customer> OutsideQueue = new LinkedList<Customer>();
    static Queue<Customer> InsideQueue = new LinkedList<Customer>();

    static ReentrantLock QueueLock = new ReentrantLock();
    static Condition QueueCon = QueueLock.newCondition();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Time(Instant.now().getEpochSecond()).start();
         new Table().start();

      }


    }

}
```

Here is the code for the Table class:

```
public class Table extends Thread{

    String choice;

    public void run(){


       while(CafeSim.continuetoRun == true){
           CafeSim.QueueLock.lock();


          if(CafeSim.OutsideQueue.isEmpty() && CafeSim.continuetoRun == true)
        try {
               CafeSim.QueueCon.signal();
               CafeSim.QueueCon.await();

           } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           } 

          else if(CafeSim.InsideQueue.size() == 10 && CafeSim.continuetoRun == true){
              System.out.println("Seats inside filled, please wait!");

              try {
               CafeSim.QueueCon.await();
           } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           } 
          }


          else if (CafeSim.OutsideQueue.size() != 0 && CafeSim.continuetoRun == true){
              if(CafeSim.OutsideQueue.peek().choice == 1){
               choice = "juice";
                }
              else {
               choice = "coffee";
               }

               System.out.println(CafeSim.OutsideQueue.peek() + " is at the table and has ordered " + choice + "!");       
               CafeSim.InsideQueue.add(CafeSim.OutsideQueue.poll());
               CafeSim.QueueCon.signal();
               CafeSim.QueueLock.unlock();
          }  
          else {
              break;
          }
    }

       System.out.println("This should end[Table].");
       CafeSim.QueueCon.signal();
       CafeSim.QueueLock.unlock();


}
}
```

And here is the time class:

```
public class Time extends Thread{

    private long startTime;
    private long currentTime;
    boolean lastordersinformed = false;


    public Time(long timeatStart){
        this.startTime = timeatStart;
    }

    public void run(){

        while(CafeSim.continuetoRun == true){
            CafeSim.QueueLock.lock();
            currentTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();

            if(currentTime - startTime < 20){
                try {
                    CafeSim.QueueCon.signal();
                    CafeSim.QueueCon.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Time.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            else if (currentTime - startTime > 20 && lastordersinformed == false){

                System.out.println("LAST ORDERS RESTAURANT WILL CLOSE VERY SOON!");
                CafeSim.OutsideQueue.clear();
                //Waiter.timeToLeave = true;
                lastordersinformed = true;

                try {
                    CafeSim.QueueCon.signal();
                    CafeSim.QueueCon.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Time.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            else if(currentTime - startTime > 30 && lastordersinformed == true){

               CafeSim.continuetoRun = false;
               System.out.println("Cafe is closed.");

            }

            else{
            try {
                    CafeSim.QueueCon.signal();
                    CafeSim.QueueCon.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Time.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }

      System.out.println("Thread has ended.[Time]");
      CafeSim.QueueCon.signal();
      CafeSim.QueueLock.unlock();

    }

}
```

Both threads should end after 30 seconds, but for some reason they don't. Only the time thread comes to an end.

Edit: I was able to fix it!

I put while loops inside the run methods of my threads so that they would continue to run until a specific boolean was changed by the Time thread. Now during the while loop the .lock() was called multiple times by each thread and if a thread wants to release a lock at the end of its run method then it has to do .unlock() the same number of times that the lock was acquired.

Declare a variable inside the thread:

```
int numberoftimesrun = 0;
```

Whenever you acquire the lock increment that variable:

```
CafeSim.QueueLock.lock();
numberoftimesrun++;
```

Then at the end:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numberoftimesrun; i++) {
             CafeSim.QueueLock.unlock();
        }
```

Comment: There are lots of await and signal at multiple places can you narrow it down it single call per method. That would make the debugging the issue more easy.

Comment: This is only one part of the entire codebase, a lot of those wait notify are necessary for the running of the simulation. The simulation works quite well up until the point where it needs to end and...it doesn't.